# How to Install gRPC extension for live server in Cpanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I'm facing problem with installing  gRPC for PHP in liver server specially cpanel ,

**VERSION PHP 7.2**

```
The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions.
```

- I well know how to install it on local host

Answer (score 1):

Found Solution,

**gRPC** extension is available for VPS and Dedicated servers because it will need a root access to install that.Most of shared servers have limited access on the php modules that can be installed or used on the server.

Comment: Whether you call your  service provider to install it or  charge resellers from many websites that support cpanel , for example https://www.resellerspanel.com/cpanel-reseller/

Comment: I have root access, my question is, If I install it via command line it will maybe cause any problem?